# Odd field extensions, possible?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I was under the impression that for all field extensions the degree would be $2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Am I mistaken?

I am wondering as I was faced with the problem of showing that: for $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd, it implies $F(\alpha) = F$.

In advance, thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 3.

Comment: @includeCMath do you have a more in-detail description to why the field extension is 3 ? I take it this is the same as $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](2): \mathbb{Q}]$

Comment: In computing the degree of an extension you are computing the dimension of a vector space over the original field. You have linear combinations of the new elements you are adding, but you don't get to multiply the new elements together.

Comment: Thank you @MarkBennet !! Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read through all the definitions and the formal process of constructing simple algebraic extensions. $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\cong \frac{\Bbb{Q}[X]}{(X^{3}-2)}$. An explicit basis for this vector space over $F$ will be given by $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},(\sqrt[3]{2})^{2}\}$.

That is any element in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ can be written as $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c(\sqrt[3]{2})^{2}$ such that $a,b,c\in F$.

Comment: Wouldn't the basis = {$1, \sqrt[3](2)$} be sufficient, giving the field extension degree 2? I don't see why an element containing $(\sqrt[3](2))^2$ can't be constructed by using $\sqrt[3](2)$.

Comment: No. It'll probably be more helpful to us if you actually explain as to why you think that all extensions are of degree $2^{n}$.

Comment: If $(\sqrt[3]{2})^{2}=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$ for some $a,b\in F$. Then it would imply that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{2}-bx-a$ . Now recall your basic algebra. This would imply that $x^{3}-2$ is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ which is highly problematic as it must be irreducible due to Eisenstein's Criteria.